# Periodogram Interpretation

Tags: time-series, spectral-analysis

I'm trying to understand why the following definition describes a function that does the job of producing a graph where the highest point indicates the frequency of the strongest periodic signal. I've tried expanding it out and I know how to read of graphs that one might produce in R - I want to understand the mechanics of the expression. Can someone explain it without the use of Fourier Analysis or other higher maths concepts?

**Definition:**
Given a time series $s_1,\ldots,s_J$ the periodogram is defined by:

$I(\omega) = \frac{2}{J} \left\{\Big(\sum_js_j\cos(\omega\times j)\Big)^2+\Big(\sum_js_j\sin(\omega\times j) \Big)^2 \right\}$

The function $I(\omega)$ is then computed for $\omega_p=\frac{2\pi p}{J}$ with $P=0,1,\ldots,\frac{J}{2}$.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "higher maths concepts."  Should we stop at arithmetic?  Can we use Euclidean geometry?  Trigonometry?  Linear algebra?  Calculus?  Complex numbers?  Group theory?  For instance, $I$ can be understood as extracting the components of a vector in a $J+1$ dimensional vector space, and many people would not consider that a part of "higher mathematics."

Comment: I think I'd probably be able to follow an explanation along the lines of this $J+1$ dimensional vector business.

Comment: So can you explain this in the context of a $J+1$ dimensional vector space then please?